# Who was risen from death after 100 years by Allah (swt)

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, surat-al-baqarah

Assalamu alaikum,
with reference to `Ayah 259 of Surah Al Baqarah`, i tried but failed to understand the Ayah

[Surah Al Baqarah - Ayah 259](http://miraculousquran.blogspot.in/2009/08/surah-al-baqarah-2259-skeletal-system.html)

Can anyone give me the explanation for the same.

1. Who is referred in this Ayah **(Name of the person)**
2. Why was he made dead? (what sign Allah wanted to show?)
3. what is the main context / story line behind this beautiful Ayah

Comment: When reading quran, its always good to have some good authentic tafsir. Because we always need explanation about some parts. Which can be found in tafsir. SO, here's a link which must solve your problem. You can look up this same site(or anywhere else) for future reference.

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal link?

Comment: I am really sorry, totally forgot to ctrl+v :D 
http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=135&Itemid=36

Comment: I guess knowing the name will not affect the idea.

Comment: @Zeina, is it fine also if i keep studying about the Prophets (PBUT) and dont bother about knowing the name? kindly recheck the comment.

Comment: The ayah is referring to **Uzayr** (Ezra), a prophet of the Jews.

Answer (score 1):

Uzair wasn't a prophet, he was a very pious man whom Allah has singled out and showed him a great sign.

He memorized the Torah and also had a copy because at that time the Torah's were being destroyed by the tyrant at that time king Nebuchadnezzar.

I am unsure of why he departed though he did(Allah knows best)
As he walked past a desolate town in ruins he said "When will Allah give it life after its death?".

So as he fell asleep later in his journey and Allah made him die for 100 years, and brought back his life afterwards.

Allah placed an example to Uzair when he was brought back to life Allah told him to look at his food and it didn't change, then Allah told him to look at his donkey which was in bones and Allah showed him how he reassembled and put flesh into the donkey and restored it's life.

He went back to his house and his household couldn't recognize him,

> "...except the maid, who was now an old blind woman. He prayed to God to
>   cure her blindness and she could see again. He meets his son who
>   recognized him by a mole between his shoulders and was older than he
>   was."([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzair))

The Torah which he had was rotting and crumpled at that time, so he re-wrote the whole thing from memory.

> **And Allah Knows Best, May Allah Forgive Me for any mistakes I made**